# sed / awk: Delete all lines matching a word not followed by another word

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, awk

I have the following lines in my file.

```
<stuff>
test1.*test2
test1
test1.*test2
test1
<other stuff>
```

I want to delete all lines containing test1, but not followed by test2 -- which means I should end up with:

```
<stuff>
test1.*test2
test1.*test2
<other stuff>
```

I've tried a lot of regular expressions, but can't seem to crack either sed or awk. This was my latest attempt, after testing with vim regexp.

```
sed -i .bk '/^.*test1\(\(test2\)\@!.\)*$/d' file
```

(This is part of a bash script on Mac OS X)

Comment: The second `test1` is not followed by `test2`, can you rephrase? Do you mean it the other way round?

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstood my question.  The first part is the original file. Yes, there are 'test1's not followed by 'test2's.  The second part is what I should end up with.

Comment: what if the file contains `test2.*test1`? Should it be output?

Comment: My file doesn't contain that pattern.

Comment: I think that your problem definition is loosely defined. What if test2 comes before test1? Is that important?

Comment: @sin It's not important. It doesn't come before test1.

Comment: If your file doesn't contain `test2.*test1` then search each line twice `test1` then `test2`.

Comment: Probably you should edit your description and take out this `but not followed by test2` line. Otherwise some unsuspecting reader might think the answer you accepted actuaally does what you stated, which it surely doesn't (or didn't, but he changed it). However, you should add that test2 will _never_ come before test1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk '/test1/&&!/test2/{next}1' file
```

We tell awk to:

- Look for lines with `test1`.
- On the same line `test2` should not be present
- If such line is found we skip
- If such line is not found we print

```
$ cat file
<stuff>
test1.*test2
test1
test1.*test2
test1
<other stuff>
```

```
$ awk '/test1/&&!/test2/{next}1' file
<stuff>
test1.*test2
test1.*test2
<other stuff>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account the order, how about a line like `test2 test1`?

Comment: @Birei then change the second condition to `!/test1.*test2/`

Comment: @Birei there are no lines in my file that go test2 test1.  This answer fits my use case so it works.

Comment: @jaypal: I understood it from: *I want to delete all lines containing test1, but not followed by test2*, but it seems all fine as answer for the OP, so no problem.

Comment: @Birei Don't get me wrong, you have a valid point. The answer will probably have to be refined for different use cases. But this can serve as a starting point. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal: It's all ok. Simply I wanted to point out a potential problem as I had understood the question, but it's not necessary because the OP already clarified the point.

Comment: Why the `.*` in one regex and not the other? Or why is `.*` there at all?

Comment: The `.*` in `/.*test2/` is not doing anything, it can/should just be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Use two expressions. The first one skips the cases where `test1` is followed by `test2`, the second one removes `test1` - it can only be reached if `test2` wasn't there.

```
sed -e '/test1.*test2/b' -e '/test1/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep with perl regexes:

```
grep -vP 'test1(?!.*test2)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!/test1/||/test2/' file
<stuff>
test1.*test2
test1.*test2
<other stuff>
```